# Handling openfeint when offline in Unity Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, openfeint

I have successfully integrated open feint in my Unity3D Android game using this link.
http://support.openfeint.com/dev/example-integrating-ofunity-for-android-with-unity/
but i am having a problem that how can i handle the score when the device is not connected with internet?

Any help will be appreciative because i have googled a lot but could not find satisfactory answer.

Thanks